# What is "Attach volume" in Amazon Web services?

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Are the terms used in Amazon Web Services `Attach volume` and `Deattach volume` used in reference of Amazon Elastic Block Storage; exactly same as Unix/Linux `Mount` and `Unmount` a device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attach volume and detach volume is the same as opening up you're computer and attaching or detaching a new disk. After you run the attach command you still need to mount the volume on the computer, format etc... same process as after you connect a new drive.

Comment: I am new to this, I have created a 'EBS' volume for my Amazon EC2 instance and attached it to the instance but I never mounted it so how could my instance use the volume for booting?

Comment: An EBS bootable instance is formatted as part of the process of initializing it from an AMI.  That happens behind-the-scenes from a user's perspective.  Only when you allocate a new EBS volume do you have to format it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Attaching a volume means to make it physically available as a device to the operating system (as a block device).  To be used as a file system, it must be mounted.  Note that a raw EBS device is not formatted.

Here's a step-by-step guide to mounting an EBS volume

Brand-new EBS Volume:

http://support.rightscale.com/06-FAQs/FAQ_0012_-_How_do_I_partition,_format_and_mount_an_EBS_volume%3F

Pre-existing EBS Volume:

http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Region/EBS_Volumes/Actions/Attach_an_EBS_Volume_to_an_instance

Comment: By 'raw EBS' do you any EBS volume which is not a 'boot volume'?

Comment: I mean an unformatted EBS volume... one that has not been formatted for a particular file system such as xfs or whatever.

Comment: I imagine 'boot volume` should be formatted from the beginning otherwise how it will be used to boot the ec2 instance.

Comment: To the downvoter: If something is wrong with this answer, kindly explain what so we can all learn.

Comment: My upvote continues but looks like downvoter believe @bwight answer is right.

Comment: I think there was some ambiguity in my previous answer which I clarified.